# Getting warning in Sitecore Logs : [Experience Analytics]: Reducing segment

Tags: experience-analytics, performance-optimization

Getting below warning in the Sitecore logs, Current using Sitecore version 8.2 update 4

10688 01:24:44 INFO  [Experience Analytics]: Reducing segment: 'd8ba6f18-d0da-4cbb-b51f-8741c0fe9540' on date: 20-06-17 site 679248886.
8272 01:24:45 WARN  All caches have been cleared. This can decrease performance considerably.

Could you please advice is this may be the reason of slowdown the CMS/Sitecore site? and how we can correct this?

Thanks in advance!!
Pushpendra

Answer (score 1):

we also have had such errors with the reduce agent, it is a bug in Sitecore *(Ref.No. 21517)*.

```
Unfortunately, the bug is not fixed yet and we don't have ETA - but it's likely to be fixed in a major update due to complexity.
```

Please contact Sitecore Support for a hotfix, I do have a link to the hotfix but this one is especially build für Sitecore 8.2.2:

*Please find the hotfix available at the following URL:
https://dl.sitecore.net/hotfix/SC%20Hotfix%20167101-2%20Experience%20Analytics%202.0.2.zip
Be aware that the hotfix was built specifically for 8.2 Update 2, and you should not install it on other Sitecore versions or in combination with other hotfixes, unless explicitly instructed by Sitecore Support.*

In our project the reduce agent tried to reduce segments on 248 configured sites, the process took more than 4,5 hours until it hungs up and backend performance was very slow. Log entries was like:

```
20940 08:00:02 WARN  All caches have been cleared. This can decrease performance considerably. DEBUG entries have to be enabled in log4net to see the corresponding stack trace. 
93336 08:00:02 WARN  All caches have been cleared. This can decrease performance considerably.
```

Best regards

Dirk